# Changing the content of a button when clicked?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I'm trying to change the text in a button when said button is clicked. how would I go about doing that (I've been seeing many varying answers)?

the Error is: **Error   16  'System.Windows.Controls.Button' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

```
if (Result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You Reserved this seat");
    btnSeat1.Text = "Reserved";
}
```

Comment: as you say in title: `btnSeat1.Content = "Reserved";`

Comment: the code `btnSeat1.Text` should work..@The_Doctor is this `WPF or WinForms..?

Comment: is your code in wpf ?

Answer (score 3):

WinForms buttons have `Text`, WPF buttons (`System.Windows.Controls.Button`) have `Content`

`Text` is a string, `Content` can be very complex ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=vs.110).aspx))

so change you code to:

```
btnSeat1.Content = "Reserved";
```

Comment: That's what I thought you were getting at in your earlier comment lol `+1`